# How to pass object to Get-Job subprocess as reference

Tags: powershell

I need to write a powershell script that asynchronously reads from *and* writes to a `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` object. However when writing the code to simply read from the object using `Start-Job` I'm getting an error. Here's my code so far:

```
$func = {
    function CheckPort 
    {
        param (
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
            [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]$port
        )
            
        Write-Output $port.ReadLine()
    }
}

$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4, 9600, None, 8, one
$port.Open()

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {CheckPort $args[0]} -ArgumentList $port -Name “$computerName” -InitializationScript $func
```

When I run the code above, after I use `Receive-Object`   to check the output of the subprocess, I see an error. It seems that instead of the `$port` object being passed as-is, it is first serialized then unserialized:

```
Error: "Cannot convert the "System.IO.Ports.SerialPort" value of type "Deserialized.System.IO.Ports.SerialPort" to type "System.IO.Ports.SerialPort"."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [CheckPort], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,CheckPort
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Is there anyway to pass the an argument by reference using `Start-Job`? `$port.ReadLine()` is blocking and there isn't an alternative method that can just check whether there is something to read, and I need to occasionally write to the port, so I definitely need asynchronous execution here.

I get the same error if I try `$using`:

```
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4, 9600, None, 8, one
$port.Open()

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $myPort = $using:port
    Write-Output $myPort.ReadLine()
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use a run space instead? https://www.google.com/amp/s/learn-powershell.net/2016/02/14/another-way-to-get-output-from-a-powershell-runspace/amp/

Comment: start-threadjob should work

Answer (score 0):

These two methods don't serialize the objects.  You need PS 7 for `foreach-object -parallel`, but you can download [start-threadjob](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob) in PS 5.

```
Start-ThreadJob {
  $myPort = $using:port
  $myPort.ReadLine()
} | receive-job -wait -auto
```

```
foreach-object -parallel {
  $myPort = $using:port
  $myPort.ReadLine()
}
```